# Linux Perf reports less syscall events with the system-wide (-a) option than without. Why?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, profiling, perf

I am using Linux's Perf to profile an AI program's system call behavior. The program is Mozilla's Deepspeech.

Specifically, I ran `perf stat -e 'syscalls:*' ./my_program`, and the output is like this:

```
        ...
        23,058,901      syscalls:sys_enter_sched_yield                                   
        23,058,901      syscalls:sys_exit_sched_yield  
        ...
```

But when I ran `perf stat -a -e 'syscalls:*' ./my_program`, I got this:

```
        ...
               141      syscalls:sys_enter_sched_yield                                   
               141      syscalls:sys_exit_sched_yield   
        ...
```

So there is significantly more `sched_yield` syscalls in my program than in the whole system. The same can be said for `clone` (156 system-wide to 231 non-system-wide).

But my program should be part of the system, right? How could the whole system have **less** syscalls than my program?

Comment: Can you repeat the experiment with only one or two events enabled - not `-e 'syscalls:*'`, but `-e 'syscalls:sys*_sched_yield'`? `strace` or `sysdig` may be better tool to record or trace syscalls of applicaion. Yes, your program is part of the system, but two runs are different in amount of work for perf application itself, and you ask it for very huge list of events.